# OS X: "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" with only a single unsatisfiable constraint

Tags: swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, osx-yosemite, xcode6.1

I am programming a grid based view, adding NSLayoutConstraints dynamically with the following code

```
for (x, column) in enumerate(board) {
    for (y, cell) in enumerate(column) {
        // MARK: Cell set up
        cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.addSubview(cell)

        // MARK: Autolayout constraints
        // Priorities
        cell.setContentHuggingPriority(249, forOrientation: .Horizontal)
        cell.setContentHuggingPriority(249, forOrientation: .Vertical)
        cell.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(750, forOrientation: .Horizontal)
        cell.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(750, forOrientation: .Vertical)
        // Horizontal layout
        if x == 0 {
            container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: container, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 4))
        } else {
            container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: board[x - 1][y], attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 4))
            container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: board[x - 1][y], attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        }
        if x == board.count - 1 {
            container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 4))
        }
        // Vertical layout
        if y == 0 {
            container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: container, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 4))
        } else {
            container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: board[x][y - 1], attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 4))
            container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: board[x][y - 1], attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        }
        if y == board[x].count - 1 {
            container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 4))
        }
    }
}
```

But on running, the following error results

```
2014-11-05 17:12:56.333 ProjectName[21373:1094967] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000081c70 V:[NSView:0x610000121d60]-(4)-[NSView:0x610000121d60]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000081c70 V:[NSView:0x610000121d60]-(4)-[NSView:0x610000121d60]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

Now, board is an array of NSView arrays, and the NSViews are completely empty. In order to get the error output above, I initialized board as [[NSView(), NSView()]], that is, one column with two rows.

```
               x = 0
            ------------
board[x][0] | NSView() |
board[x][1] | NSView() |
            ------------
```

My dynamic layout code works for a single row with an arbitrary number of columns, but it breaks for some reason when given any more than one row. The code to auto layout the rows is the exact same as the column code, making adjustments for Left→Top, Right→Bottom, etc

Anyone know why having more than one row is breaking my code?

I'm using Xcode 6.1 with a deployment target of 10.10, programming in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that both items in the constraint are the same view: `[NSView:0x610000121d60]`.  I think you're putting the same view into the board array twice.

#### UPDATE

If you want to create an array of views:

```
let column = (0 ..< height).map { _ in NSView() }
```

Comment: `*facepalm*` I populated the board using the builtin array constructor `[NSView](count: Int, repeatedValue: NSView())`. So turns out that method doesn't create a new instance for each slot, but reuses the reference to the same instance.

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you do that correctly.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! This has been a roadblock for hours! I should have just compared the NSView addresses haha